# How to deselect filtered items in a listview?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a listview bound to a collectionview, which in course gets filterd.

When the Filter is applied, the listview retains it´s original selection, which is somewhat confusing for the users since an object is still selected which they can no longer see.

I would be gladif someone has a suggestion on how to deselect all items which were sorted out by the filter of the collectionview.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem when updating two gridviews. Setting SelectedIndex = -1 with the SelectedIndexChanging and SelectedIndexChanged worked for me.

Specific to ListView:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.selectedindex(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That approach won´t work for me since i use a MVVM-Model. Furthermore i don´t want to deselect everything, but just to deselect all filtered objects.